# tensor slicing in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensor

I want to do the same numpy operation as follow to make a custom layer

```
img=cv2.imread('img.jpg') # img.shape =>(600,600,3)

mask=np.random.randint(0,2,size=img.shape[:2],dtype='bool')

img2=np.expand_dims(img,axis=0) #img.shape => (1,600,600,3)

img2[:,mask,:].shape # =>  (1, 204030, 3)
```

this is my first attemp but I failed. I can't do the same operation for  for tensorflow tensors

```
class Sampling_layer(keras.layers.Layer):

    def __init__(self,sampling_matrix):
        super(Sampling_layer,self).__init__()
        self.sampling_matrix=sampling_matrix

    def call(self,input_img):
        return input_img[:,self.sampling_matrix,:]
```

More Explanations:

I want to define a keras layer so that given a batch of images it use a sampling matrix and give me a batch of sampled vectors for the images.The sampling matrix is  a random boolean matrix the same size as the image. The slicing operation I used is straight forward for numpy arrays and works perfectly. but I can't get it done with tensors in tensorflow. I tried to use loops to perform the operation I want manually but I failed.

Comment: your question is not clear. Your class is not looking like your try to reproduce the first code. Why did you add it to the question ?

Comment: @Andrey I want to define a keras layer so that given a batch of images it use a sampling matrix and give me a batch of sampled vectors for the images.The sampling matrix a random boolean same size as the image. The slicing operation I used is straight forward for numpy arrays and works perfectly. but I can't get it done with tensors in tensorflow. I tried to use loops to perform the operation I want manually but I failed. I appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

# Batch of images
img=np.random.normal(size=[2,600,600,3]) # img.shape =>(600,600,3)

# You'll need to match the first 3 dimensions of mask with the img
# for that we'll repeat the first axis twice
mask=np.random.randint(0,2,size=img.shape[1:3],dtype='bool')
mask = np.repeat(np.expand_dims(mask, axis=0), 2, axis=0)

# Defining input layers
inp1 = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(600,600,3))
mask_inp = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(600,600))

# The layer you're looking for
out = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.boolean_mask(x[0], x[1]) )([inp1, mask])

model = tf.keras.models.Model([inp1, mask_inp], out)

# Predict on sample data
toy_out = model.predict([img, mask])
```

Note that both your images and mask needs to have the same batch size. I couldn't find a solution to make this work without repeating the mask on batch axis to match the batch size of images. This is the only possible solution that came to my mind, (assuming that your mask changes for every batch of data).